# Putting the background of another button on the button background Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

i want to make

if i click Button1, Main ButtonBackground image = Button1.Background image.

if i click Button2, Main Button background image = Button2.Background image.

I want to make for my app has about 80 imageButton and character. If i learn a method my work must easilier.

[image]

My.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

    Button btn1 = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn2);
    Button btnMain = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnMain);

    btn1.Click += delegate {
        btnMain.SetBackgroundResource(/*I cant fill in method*/);                
    };
    btn2.Click += delegate {
        btnMain.SetBackgroundResource(/*I cant fill in method*/);
    };
}
```

layout1.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_yellow" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_green" />
    <Button
        android:text="Main Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnMain" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple lambdas, and instead of using SetBackgroundResource you can use setBackgroundDrawable/getBackgroundDrawable which in Xamarin is backed to the property Background:

```
Button btnMain;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

    Button btn1 = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn2);
    btnMain = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnMain);

    btn1.Click += ChangeBackground;
    btn2.Click += ChangeBackground;
}

private void ChangeBackground(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    btnMain.Background = btn.Background;
}
```

Comment: The perfect answer. I totally wanted this method. Thank you.

Comment: @MahmutBedir, if you accept this answer, why you don't [mark this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?